# Solving dynamic optimization with non-binding inequality constraint

Tags: inequality, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, constraints

I want to solve a problem similar to the following discrete and finite time horizon dynamic optimization problem :
\begin{equation} 
\begin{split}
&\max_{\{d_t\}} \sum_{t=0}^{T} - \left [ f(s_t) + k(d_t)  \right ] + F(s_{T+1})\\
& s.t. \left \{ \begin{array}{ll} 
s_{t+1} = s_t + d_t \\
s_t < A \\
s_0 \in \mathbb{R}_+ \\
s_T = A \\
\end{array}
\right.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

I am able to solve the problem without the inequality constraint $s_t < A$ using Lagrangian multiplier which leads to a recursive equation on $s_t$ which I am able to solve numerically afterwards.

I wish to find a similar recursive equation, but this time when considering $s_t < A$. How should I take this inequality constraint into account when computing the Lagrangian first order conditions ?

Comment: Introduce a slack variable $\epsilon$ such that $s_t-A+\epsilon^2 = 0$

Comment: Thank you @Cesareo for your answer. Then how should I deal with the slack variable when deriving the first order condition ? Is there a direct method regarding slack variables ?

Comment: Handle it as more a variable. The Lagrangian now reads $L(d_t,\lambda,\epsilon)$ so regarding  $\epsilon$ we have $L_{\epsilon} = 2\lambda_i\epsilon = 0$ and $L_{\lambda_i} = s_t -A+\epsilon^2=0$ one additional condition.

Comment: But there is no new co-state variable ? I am not sure on how to write the Lagrangian is this framework.

Comment: $L(d_t,\lambda,\epsilon) =  \sum_{t=0}^{T} - \left [ f(s_t) + k(d_t)  \right ] + F(s_{T+1})+\lambda_1(s_{t+1} - s_t - d_t)+\lambda_2(s_t-A+\epsilon_1^2)+\lambda_3(S_T-A)+\lambda_4(s_0-\epsilon_2^2)$

Comment: The Lagrangian multiplers should also have "time" indices no ?

Comment: I wrote a short  answer. To consider for $t = 1,2,\cdots,T$ you should consider also different $\lambda$'s so $\lambda_{1t}(s_{t+1}-s_t-d_t),\ \ t = 1,2,\cdots,T$ etc.

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand why you wrote $L_\epsilon = 0$ though ? Is this part of the FOC when considering a slack variable ? I don't understand how to get rid off the new co-state variable introduced when considering the new equality constraint with the slack variable. And should the constraint be $s_t - A + \epsilon_t^2 = 0$ where $\epsilon$ is also time-dependent ?

Comment: Introducing $\epsilon_t$ in $s_t-A+\epsilon_t^2=0$ it appears into the Lagrangian as $\sum_t \lambda_t(s_t-A+\epsilon_t^2)$ and in the stationary conditions appears as $L_{\epsilon_t}=2\lambda_t \epsilon_t = 0$ so it is mandatory that or $\epsilon_t=0$ or $\lambda_t=0$ or both null.

Comment: This way the solution assumes a combinatoric procedure searching for the possible $\lambda$'s and $\epsilon$'s

Comment: Thank you very much. This seems to work, but I do not understand how one can justify the "stationary condition" stating that $L_{\epsilon_t}=0$ ? Is this somehow related to the KKT condition ?

Answer (score 1):

I will present a reduced example shoving how to solve this kind of problems using the classical procedure of Lagrange multipliers. To apply this technique, previously we transform the inequalities into equalities with the help of the $\epsilon_k$ slack variables.

First form the Lagrangian

$$
L(x,u,\lambda,\epsilon) = \phi(x_{n+1})-f(x,u)+\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_k(x_{k+1}-x_k-u_k) + \sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_{n+k}(x_k-A+\epsilon_k^2)+\lambda_{2n+1}(x_n-A)
$$

where

$$
\phi(x_{n+1}) = x_{n+1}^2\\
f(x,u) = \min(\max)\sum_{k=1}^na x_k^2+b u_k^2
$$

Now considering $n = 5$ the stationary conditions are

$$
\nabla L = \left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 2 \epsilon _1 \lambda _6&=&0 \\
 2 \epsilon _2 \lambda _7&=&0 \\
 2 \epsilon _3 \lambda _8&=&0 \\
 2 \epsilon _4 \lambda _9&=&0 \\
 2 \epsilon _5 \lambda _{10}&=&0 \\
 -u_1-x_1+x_2&=&0 \\
 -u_2-x_2+x_3&=&0 \\
 -u_3-x_3+x_4&=&0 \\
 -u_4-x_4+x_5&=&0 \\
 -u_5-x_5+x_6&=&0 \\
 \epsilon _1^2-A+x_1&=&0 \\
 \epsilon _2^2-A+x_2&=&0 \\
 \epsilon _3^2-A+x_3&=&0 \\
 \epsilon _4^2-A+x_4&=&0 \\
 \epsilon _5^2-A+x_5&=&0 \\
 x_5-A&=&0 \\
 2 b u_1+\lambda _1&=&0 \\
 2 b u_2+\lambda _2&=&0 \\
 2 b u_3+\lambda _3&=&0 \\
 2 b u_4+\lambda _4&=&0 \\
 2 b u_5+\lambda _5&=&0 \\
 -\lambda _1+\lambda _6-2 a x_1&=&0 \\
 \lambda _1-\lambda _2+\lambda _7-2 a x_2&=&0 \\
 \lambda _2-\lambda _3+\lambda _8-2 a x_3&=&0 \\
 \lambda _3-\lambda _4+\lambda _9-2 a x_4&=&0 \\
 \lambda _4-\lambda _5+\lambda _{10}+\lambda _{11}-2 a x_5&=&0 \\
 \lambda _5+2 x_6&=&0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Solving this system of equations we obtain for the parametric values $a = 2, b = 2, A = 1, n = 5$

follows the $\min$ strategy (in red $u$ and in blue $x$)

[image]

and the $\max$ strategy

[image]

Any way, this kind of problem can be satisfactorily solved with a quadratic programming package, without the need for the slack variables introduction. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming

I hope this helps.

Comment: This definitely help. Thank's a lot.